# (Piwik 1.12) What are the differences in idaction_url, idaction_url_ref, idaction_name, idaction_name_ref of "piwik_log_link_visit_action" table?

Tags: matomo

There are four columns related to `piwik_log_action` table in Piwik's `piwik_log_link_visit_action` table.

- idaction_url
- idaction_url_ref
- idaction_name
- idaction_name_ref

What are the differences in these four columns? (url/name and with/without `_ref`)

Comment: For others searching for similar information, also check the Piwik developer documentation: https://developer.piwik.org/guides/persistence-and-the-mysql-backend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With/Without _ref:

- Entries without _ref are for the actual page visited during this action
- Entries with _ref are for the referrer (previous page) for this action

For each of these pages:

- url is the actual web address of the page
- name is the title of the page

Comment: Thank you. :) Sorry for not accepting your answer soon.